# How can I copy a file from s3 bucket into an ec2 instance using userdata inside a cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I need to be able to copy some files from s3 bucket into ec2 instance during launch time . Is it possible to do so via user data section of the cloudformation template?

Fyi, I have the role attached to the instance to access s3 and I am able to copy files using aws cli but I need to be able to do so via user data inside cloudformation  without using aws cli, if possible at all.

**Edit--**

Object in s3 is publicly accessible at the moment and the instance is using a custom red hat ami.

Comment: Why can't you just use same awscli commands (that worked for you "manually") in your user-data?

Comment: aws cli is not installed by default on the ami which I am using. I can install it anyways but I am exploring any other way  to copy files without using aws cli.

Comment: You can use something like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html but I would rather not go that way :)

Comment: Is the object in Amazon S3 publicly accessible, or is it only accessible via the assigned IAM Role? Which operating system is on the instance?

Comment: @John Yes. It's publicly accessible at the moment. The instance is using a custom RedHat image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object in Amazon S3 is publicly accessible, you could download it with `curl`:

```
curl -o output.file https://my-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/file.txt
```

If `wget` is installed, you could use that instead.

If the object is private, it will require authentication using the role. This will require some form of software to be installed, so it would be simpler to just install the AWS CLI.

Comment: Thanks John for making it clear ! I will definitely go for aws cli.